# Linker errors in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, linker, header, wxwidgets

I'm writing a C++ wxWidgets calculator application. I have this header file where I declare the various operations and constants that my app supports. When I try to compile, I get 258 **LNK2005** errors, such as:

> Error LNK2005 "bool __cdecl isBinary(class wxString)"
> (?isBinary@@YA_NVwxString@@@Z) already defined in
> app.obj   C:\Users\giorg\Desktop\Visual
> Studio\wxWidgetsTest\wxWidgetsTest\events.obj 1   ikeCalculator
>
> Error LNK2005 "class wxString unary::tan" (?tan@unary@@3VwxString@@A)
> already defined in app.obj    C:\Users\giorg\Desktop\Visual
> Studio\wxWidgetsTest\wxWidgetsTest\events.obj 1   ikeCalculator

And so on for everything in this file. There seems to be an error for every time one of these objects is referenced in other files.

```
#pragma once
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <map>

namespace binary {
    wxString add(L"+"), sub(L"-");
    wxString mul(L"\u00D7"), div(L"\u00F7");
    wxString pow(L"^");
}
namespace unary {
    wxString sqrt(L"\u221A");
    wxString sin(L"sin"), cos(L"cos"), tan(L"tan");
    wxString arcsin(L"arcsin"), arccos(L"arccos"), arctan(L"tan");
}
namespace constant {
    wxString pi(L"\u03C0");
    wxString light_speed(L"c");
    wxString avogadro_number(L"N\u1D00");
    wxString atomic_mass_unit(L"u");
    wxString planck(L"h");
    wxString gas(L"R");
    wxString gravity_acceleration(L"g");
    wxString golden_ratio(L"\u03D5");
}

namespace calc
{
    std::map < wxString, std::function<long double(long double, long double)> > binary
    {
        {binary::add, [](long double a, long double b) { return a + b; }},
        {binary::sub, [](long double a, long double b) { return a - b; }},
        {binary::mul, [](long double a, long double b) { return a * b; }},
        {binary::div, [](long double a, long double b) { return a / b; }},
        {binary::pow, [](long double a, long double b) { return pow(a, b); }}
    };

    std::map < wxString, std::function<long double(long double)> > unary
    {
        {unary::sqrt, [](long double n) { return sqrt(n); }},
        {unary::sin, [](long double n) { return sin(n * 3.14159265359 / 180); }},       //trasformazione da rad a gradi
        {unary::cos, [](long double n) { return cos(n * 3.14159265359 / 180); }},
        {unary::tan, [](long double n) { return tan(n * 3.14159265359 / 180); }},
        {unary::arcsin, [](long double n) { return asin(n) * 180 / 3.14159265359; } },  //trasformazione da rad a gradi
        {unary::arccos, [](long double n) { return acos(n) * 180 / 3.14159265359; } },
        {unary::arctan, [](long double n) { return atan(n) * 180 / 3.14159265359; } }
    };

    std::map < wxString, long double > constant
    {
        {constant::pi, 3.14159265359},
        {constant::light_speed, 299792458},
        {constant::avogadro_number, 6.02214086 * pow(10, 23)},
        {constant::atomic_mass_unit, 1.67 * pow(10, -27)},
        {constant::planck, 6.626 * pow(10, -34)},
        {constant::gas, 8.314},
        {constant::gravity_acceleration, 9.80665},
        {constant::golden_ratio, 1.6180339887}
    };
}


inline bool isBinary(wxString needle)
{
    return (calc::binary.count(needle));
}

inline bool isUnary(wxString needle)
{
    return (calc::unary.count(needle));
}

inline bool isConstant(wxString needle)
{
    return (calc::constant.count(needle));
}
```

**EDIT**

I followed some advice and modified my code like so (still having the issue):

**ops.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <map>

namespace binary {
    extern const wxString add, sub, mul, div;
}
namespace unary {
    extern const wxString sqrt, sin, cos, tan, arcsin, arccos, arctan;
}
namespace constant {
    extern const wxString pi, light_speed, avogadro_number, atomic_mass_unit, planck, gas, gravity_acceleration, golden_ratio;
}

namespace calc
{
    extern const std::map < wxString, std::function<long double(long double, long double)> > binary;
    extern const std::map < wxString, std::function<long double(long double)> > unary;
    extern const std::map < wxString, long double > constant;
}

bool isBinary(wxString needle);
bool isUnary(wxString needle);
bool isConstant(wxString needle);
```

**ops.cpp**

```
#include "ops.h"

namespace binary {
    const wxString add(L"+"), sub(L"-");
    const wxString mul(L"\u00D7"), div(L"\u00F7");
    const wxString pow(L"^");
}
namespace unary {
    const wxString sqrt(L"\u221A");
    const wxString sin(L"sin"), cos(L"cos"), tan(L"tan");
    const wxString arcsin(L"arcsin"), arccos(L"arccos"), arctan(L"tan");
}
namespace constant {
    const wxString pi(L"\u03C0");
    const wxString light_speed(L"c");
    const wxString avogadro_number(L"N\u1D00");
    const wxString atomic_mass_unit(L"u");
    const wxString planck(L"h");
    const wxString gas(L"R");
    const wxString gravity_acceleration(L"g");
    const wxString golden_ratio(L"\u03D5");
}

namespace calc
{
    const std::map < wxString, std::function<long double(long double, long double)> > binary
    {
        {binary::add, [](long double a, long double b) { return a + b; }},
        {binary::sub, [](long double a, long double b) { return a - b; }},
        {binary::mul, [](long double a, long double b) { return a * b; }},
        {binary::div, [](long double a, long double b) { return a / b; }},
        {binary::pow, [](long double a, long double b) { return pow(a, b); }}
    };

    const std::map < wxString, std::function<long double(long double)> > unary
    {
        {unary::sqrt, [](long double n) { return sqrt(n); }},
        {unary::sin, [](long double n) { return sin(n * 3.14159265359 / 180); }},       //trasformazione da rad a gradi
        {unary::cos, [](long double n) { return cos(n * 3.14159265359 / 180); }},
        {unary::tan, [](long double n) { return tan(n * 3.14159265359 / 180); }},
        {unary::arcsin, [](long double n) { return asin(n) * 180 / 3.14159265359; } },  //trasformazione da rad a gradi
        {unary::arccos, [](long double n) { return acos(n) * 180 / 3.14159265359; } },
        {unary::arctan, [](long double n) { return atan(n) * 180 / 3.14159265359; } }
    };

    const std::map < wxString, long double > constant
    {
        {constant::pi, 3.14159265359},
        {constant::light_speed, 299792458},
        {constant::avogadro_number, 6.02214086 * pow(10, 23)},
        {constant::atomic_mass_unit, 1.67 * pow(10, -27)},
        {constant::planck, 6.626 * pow(10, -34)},
        {constant::gas, 8.314},
        {constant::gravity_acceleration, 9.80665},
        {constant::golden_ratio, 1.6180339887}
    };
}


bool isBinary(wxString needle)
{
    return (calc::binary.count(needle));
}

bool isUnary(wxString needle)
{
    return (calc::unary.count(needle));
}

bool isConstant(wxString needle)
{
    return (calc::constant.count(needle));
}
```

**EDIT**

Another try I made (now just 19 errors):

**ops.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <map>

namespace binary
{
    extern const wxString add, sub, mul, div, pow;
}

namespace unary
{
    extern const wxString sqrt, sin, cos, tan, arcsin, arccos, arctan;
}

namespace constant
{
    extern const wxString pi, avogadro_number, planck, gas, atomic_mass_unit;
}

namespace calc
{
    extern std::map < wxString, std::function<long double(long double, long double)> > binary;
    extern std::map < wxString, std::function<long double(long double)> > unary;
    extern std::map < wxString, long double > constant;
}

bool isBinary(wxString needle);
bool isUnary(wxString needle);
bool isConstant(wxString needle);
```

**ops.cpp**

```
#include "ops.h"

namespace binary
{
    extern const wxString 
        add(L"+"), 
        sub(L"-"), 
        mul(L"\u00D7"), 
        div(L"\u00F7"), 
        pow(L"^");
}

namespace unary
{
    extern const wxString 
        sqrt(L"\u221A"),
        sin(L"sin"), 
        cos(L"cos"), 
        tan(L"tan"),
        arcsin(L"arcsin"),
        arccos(L"arccos"),
        arctan(L"arctan");
}

namespace constant
{
    extern const wxString
        pi(L"\u03C0"),
        avogadro_number(L"N\u2090"),
        planck(L"h"),
        gas(L"R"),
        atomic_mass_unit(L"u");
}

namespace calc
{
    extern std::map < wxString, std::function<long double(long double, long double)> > binary = {
        {binary::add, [](long double a, long double b) { return a + b; }},
        {binary::sub, [](long double a, long double b) { return a - b; }},
        {binary::mul, [](long double a, long double b) { return a * b; }},
        {binary::div, [](long double a, long double b) { return a / b; }},
        {binary::pow, [](long double a, long double b) { return pow(a, b); }}
    };
    extern std::map < wxString, std::function<long double(long double)> > unary = {
        {unary::sqrt, [](long double n) { return sqrt(n); }}
    };
    extern std::map < wxString, long double > constant = {
        {constant::pi, 3.1415926535}
    };
}

bool isBinary(wxString needle)
{
    return (calc::binary.count(needle));
}

bool isUnary(wxString needle)
{
    return (calc::unary.count(needle));
}

bool isConstant(wxString needle)
{
    return (calc::constant.count(needle));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that because you have symbol definitions in a `.h` file, each of your symbols gets defined in each compilation unit. That is, each symbol is defined in `A.cpp`, and then *again* in `B.cpp`, `C.cpp`, and so on. In the end you have several symbols with the same name, and that is not allowed.

The solution is to move all those definitions to one single `.cpp` file, and then declare them in the `.h` file by using the `extern` keyword. For example: `extern wxString sqrt;`.

Also, since you most likely do not intend to modify the value of those symbols, all of them should be `const wxString` instead of just `wxString`.

Comment: I tried what you said. Now the errors are 241 plus a LNK4042. I copied the code in `ops.h` into `ops.cpp` along with `#include "ops.h"`  (and I also added `const`'s). [This is the code for the header.](https://pasteboard.co/K8JGW3K.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried..

```
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#endif
```

I'm only a beginner but I know pragma once != ifndef.
Or perhaps something like that in your .cpp.

Comment: `#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <map>` and then `#endif` at the end didn't work.

Comment: The pasteboard link in your other comment doesn't go anywhere for me. As Lauri said the issue looks to us like you are defining things in more than one place. When you #include something it basically directly copies the code from the #included file into the file you are adding the #include. You should use header guards to avoid things getting included twice and thus defining things twice. Only #include something if the file depends on the definitions or declarations from it. Is wx/wx.h stored locally for you? If not use <wx/wx.h>. https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-files/

Comment: I've edited the post since the link doesn't work anymore. Regarding the header guards, isn't `#pragma once` OK too? And yes, I have my wxWidgets files stored locally, so `#include "wx/wx.h"` is fine.

Comment: I officially don't know. I assume you have _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS in your preprocessor definitions?
The code you gave compiled fine for me except for the lack of main().

#pragma once is not an official part of the C++ language, and not all compilers support it.

Comment: I take that back, I believe this has the answer for you. I'm too tired to write out how you'd do it but I think you can solve your problem after giving it a quick read.
https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/sharing-global-constants-across-multiple-files-using-inline-variables/

Comment: I added `extern` in the .cpp file as well, and now the errors are just 19.

Comment: So now your constants are only defined in your .cpp and forward declared in your header, right? If so, any more linker errors you get will likely be for variables defined in multiple places and your task would then be to track them down, make sure they are defined in one place and declared in other places they are needed. Unless you do need to define them in multiple places, in which case you can use inline constexpr variables.

Comment: Every single thing in the .h or .cpp is NEVER defined anywhere else. I found out that now, after the addition of the extern keyword in the .cpp file, the wxString's aren't giving any errors anymore. The maps still do however cause linker problems.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have any experience with maps, sorry. If you post the error I could possibly try to help but I don't know. It looks to me that you have it defined in .cpp and declared in .h so I don't know why it would cause a linker error. Maybe it would be best to mark an answer and ask a new question asking about linker errors with maps.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't matter anymore. When I figured out the problem was just the maps I moved their definitions in my `Main` frame class, and everything works fine now. Your link about global variables is what helped me fix the rest, I think you should repost it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Go ahead and select Lauri's answer then, it is nearly the same as mine without the link for further explanation. Anyone with the same problem as you should be helped by that answer and if not then they can look here to better understand the issue. Glad to hear you got it working!

Comment: Strange, the `extern` keyword in the .cpp file is causing problems now. I removed it (now it's present only in the header file) and everything is fine. I guess the solution was just to remove the maps and add `extern` to the header all along.